# What is the entropy change due to work?

Tags: thermodynamics, work, entropy

The equation $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$ tells us the entropy change due to heat transfer. Likewise, the equation $dS=\frac{P}{T}dV$ tells us the entropy change due to a volume change. However, I am not sure how entropy of a system would change when work is done on it. Since work involves both a change in volume and an energy transfer, the entropy change due to work should have two terms: (1) entropy change due to energy transferred via work (2) entropy change due to volume change. (1) is where I am getting stuck. $dS=\frac{dQ}{T}$ only applies to energy transfer via heat transfer, *not work*. How would one calculate the entropy change due to work when there is no formula that tells you how a system's entropy change due to energy transferred by work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation for entropy change applies only to a reversible path.  It gives the wrong answer for an irreversible path.  To get the entropy change for any change in thermodynamic state, you devise (dream up) a reversible path between the same two end states, and evaluate the integral of dQ/T for that reversible path.  It doesn't matter whether work is done or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I can choose any path to calculate the entropy change between two states, can I treat a work process (which involves change in both energy and volume) as two separate processes with one being a pure heat transfer and the other being a pure volume change and calculate the total entropy change by just adding the entropy  changes of the two separate processes?

Comment: You can't choose any path; you can choose any **reversible** path to calculate the entropy change.  All reversible paths (and there are an infinite number of these, give exactly the value for the integral of dQ/T.  The work processes for these paths can be whatever they turn out to be.  But, you certainly don't need to use a direct path, and you can break the overall path into separate reversible sub-paths.

Comment: I have no idea what your are saying.  Give me a specific example of two (well-defined) end states, and I will illustrate how to get the entropy change.